# argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA in R

Tags: r, numeric, na

I am trying to write a function to calculate the mean of a column. The function has the arguments directory and column_name. However, I keep getting the error "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA":

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant) {

    directoryVal <- directory
    pollutantVal <- pollutant

    pollutantData <- read.csv(directoryVal)
    meanVal <- mean(pollutantData$pollutantVal, na.rm = TRUE)

}
```

I called it by:

```
pollutantmean("001.csv", "nitrate")
```

"nitrate" is one of the column names.

Note that the following works, so I'm not sure why it's not working in my function:

```
mydata <- read.csv("001.csv")
mean(mydata$nitrate, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `meanVal <- mean(pollutantData[pollutantVal], na.rm = TRUE)`, indeed your data frame `pollutantData` doesn't have any column call `pollutantVall`, so you have `pollutantData$pollutantVal` which is `NULL`. If you wan to access to a data frame column using a character, you have to use the square brackets.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add a correction.
It should actually be

```
meanVal <- mean(pollutantData[,pollutantVal], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Note the `,` before the `pollutantVal` since `pollutantVal` is a column and needs to be indexed as such.